# PHPUnit Assertions project

Tags: php, phpunit, swagger-2.0, swagger-php

I am working on a PHP project that requires validating a JSON request to a predefined schema, that is available in swagger. Now I have done my research and have found that the best project for this is SwaggerAssertions:

https://github.com/Maks3w/SwaggerAssertions

Within SwaggerAssertions/tests/PhpUnit/AssertsTraitTest.php, I would love to make use of the testAssertRequestBodyMatch method, where you do this:

```
self::assertRequestBodyMatch($request, $this->schemaManager, '/api/pets', 'post');
```

This assertion above does exactly what I need, but if I pass a invalid request it causes a fatal error. I want to trap this and handle the response back rather than the app quitting altogether.

How can I make use of this project, even though it looks like its all for PHPUnit? I am not too sure how one would make use of this project in normal PHP production code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fork the project and study how the `SchemaManager` class works. Change it so it works the way you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assertions throw exceptions if the condition is not met. If an exception is thrown, it will stop all following code from being executed until it's caught in a `try catch` block. Uncaught exceptions will cause a fatal error and the program will exit.

All you need to do to prevent your app from crashing, is handling the exception:

```
try {
    self::assertRequestBodyMatch($request, $this->schemaManager, '/api/pets', 'post');

    // Anything here will only be executed if the assertion passed

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // This will be executed if the assertion,
    // or any other statement in the try block failed

    // You should check the exception and handle it accordingly
    if ($e instanceof \PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException) {
        // Do something if the assertion failed
    }

    // If you don't recognise the exception, re-throw it
    throw $e;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this. Your post made me realise what I was doing wrong. I was do this in the catch block: catch Exception $e). Note, I had no backslash before it.